# Making a Transitive Pair Set using STL C++

Tags: c++, stl, set, transitive-closure

I'd like to create a set which has transitive pairs. My input will be of the form `pair<int, int>` and I need a set which has all transitive pairs for the given inputs.
For example, if I have pairs {1, 2} {2, 1} {2, 3} {3,4} as inputs, then I need to have a SET which has pairs { {1,2}, {2,1}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {1, 4},  {2, 4} }. I also need to find whether a given pair is a member of this transitive set.
Is there any built-in data structure/STL library that will allow me to accomplish this in C++?

Comment: Using a [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) would be the obvious answer

Answer (score 1):

You have a graph and you want to turn it into a free category, AKA the transitive closure of that graph.

Your `int` pair elements are vertices, the pairs themselves are edges, that's your graph. Now a free category on a graph is that graph with an edge composition law, and all additional edges that can be produced by the law. The law says that

- if there is an edge (or "arrow" as the category theory names it) `f` that runs from `a` to `b`
- and an edge `g` that runs from `b` to `c`
- then there's another edge denoted `f∘g` that runs from `a` to `c`
- the composition is associative (`(f∘g)∘h = f∘(g∘h)`)

(Every category also have unit edges, denoted `1`<sub>`a`</sub> that run from `a` to `a` for every vertex `a`, and a law which says that for every arrow `f` that runs from `a` to `b`, `1`<sub>`a`</sub>`∘f = f∘1`<sub>`b`</sub>`= f`, but we are not talking about those).

<sub>The general education part of this answer is hereby completed.</sub>

There are no relevant algorithms in the C++ standard library, but you may want to check `boost::graph` or any other graph-oriented library. `boost::graph` has the `transitive_closure` method which is just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent your set with:

```
set<pair<int, int>> myset;
```

The transitive closure could then be computed with:

```
void transitive_closure(set<pair<int, int>>& s)
{
    set<pair<int, int>> a;   // missing nodes to add
    for (auto i = s.cbegin(); i != s.cend(); i++)
    {
        for (auto j = i; ++j != s.cend(); j)
        {
            if (i->second == j->first 
                  && i->first != j->second 
                  && s.count(make_pair(i->first, j->second))==0 )
                a.insert(make_pair(i->first, j->second));
        }
    }
    if (!a.empty()) {
        for (auto p : a)
            s.insert(p);
        transitive_closure(s);
    }
}
```

It's not the most optimized algorithm, because the recursion will repeat some comparisons.  But it works.  By he way,  I think you've forgotten {2, 3} in your result set.

To check if a pair belongs to the set, just check if `s.count(make_pair(i->first, j->second)!=0`

Comment: I'm getting this error: 'class std::set<std::pair<int, int> >' has no member named 'cbegin', 'cend' , | base operand of '->' is not a pointer| Also {         for (auto p : a) } <- This also throws up another error.

Comment: Hm... I compiled and tested it with msvc2013. What compiler do you use ?

Comment: @user3125772 `.cbegin()` and `.cend()` are C++11 (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/). If you use gnu, don't forget the `-std=c++11` compiler option.  Otherwhise you could use `.begin()` and `.end()`, their non const equivalent.

Comment: I'm making the following pairs: pair {1 1}pair {1 2}
 pair {2 1}
 pair {2 2}
 pair{ 2 4}pair 3 3
 pair 3 4
 pair 4 2
 pair 4 3
 pair 4 4
 pair 5 5, after that I'm calling the transitive closure function. So basically 1,3 should now be in the transitive set. ((1,2)(2,4)(4,3) so I want (1,3) in the transitive set too) But it still says "NO"..!

Comment: Can I use a binary tree?

Comment: With `input[]={{1,1},{1,2},{2,1},{2,2},{2,4},{3,3},{3,4},{4,2},{4,3},{4,4},{5,5}}`, I get the following closure set: `{{1,1}{1,2}{1,3}{1,4}{2,1}{2,2}{2,3}{2,4}{3,2}{3,3}{3,4}{4,2}{4,3}{4,4}{5,5}}` so 1,3 is in...

Comment: If I want to check programatically, `cout << "(1,3) " << ((myset.count(make_pair(1, 3)) != 0) ? "is":"is not" ) << " in\n";` also confirms that the pair is in.  In fact sets are typically implemented as binary search trees.